# Meaning of "the price we must pay for progress"?

Tags: idioms

In this sentence :

> The loss of biodiversity is **the price we must pay for progress**

"
Or another sentence :

> Part of **the price we must pay for progress** is to recognize the
>   degree of pollution that our progress has brought into our water, food
>   and air.

I think the expression  "**the price we must pay for progress**." is being used as an idiom, meaning  "have to accept". Is that correct?

Comment: You may also want to check out [our sister-site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The expression is idiomatic but not for "have to accept", (at least in my interpretation of "have to accept" meaning that we must be resigned to the (whatever)).  In return for the benefits of "progress", there is a "price to pay", in terms of losing something.  An example would be that the loss of much of the rain forest and its biodiversity is the price we're paying for the destruction of the rain forest for other human-centric uses such as farming, roads, lumber and other types of development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *to pay the price* is an idiom with that meaning (with a negative connotation):

> to accept the unpleasant results of some action

From [the Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+the+price).